# Relating videos in the slideshow to articles in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, slideshow

I've created a videos slideshow using views slideshow but there is a problem. I want to relate the videos in the slideshow to the articles.

For example, if article 1 has vocabulary terms - tag1, tag2, tag4. Then those videos which have these terms in them should be visible in the slideshow.

How can I do this?

In the view I've set a contextual filter of "Has taxonomy term ID" but whenever I set it the slideshow disappears.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add Content:Nid as a contextual filter
2.Configure it like this: WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE
-Provide default value > Type> Content ID from the URL

3.Add contextual filter Content: Has taxonomy term ID
4.Configure it like this:
WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE:
Provide default value>Taxonomy term ID from the URL
Load default filter from term page - yes
Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks - yes
Limit terms by vocabulary -yes
Vocabularies -

And that's it, you can find example and more details here> http://www.pixelwrapped.com/blog/related-articles-block-view-nodes-common-taxonomy-terms